# Java OpenGL EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION on glDrawArrays only on NVIDIA

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, nvidia, gldrawarrays

I'm working on a game in java using lwjgl and it's OpenGL implementation.
Never had any problems until I exchanged it with a colleague who uses NVIDIA instead of AMD, and suddenly it crashes on a line that works on AMD but it only crashes at that point in the code. That is the weardest part because I use the same method to create the VBOs from .obj-files. I even tried it with the same file but still at that point it crashes on all other occasion not.
Could it be maybe a wrong set flag or something?  I hope somebody here can help.

```
for (int i = 0; i < material.length; i++) {
  material[i].activate();

  glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
  GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexVBO[i]);
  glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);

  if (normalsEnabled[i]) {
    glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, normalVBO[i]);
    glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);
  }

  if (material[i].getTexture() != null) {
    glEnableClientState(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, textureVBO[i]);
    GL11.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);

    GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glDrawArrays(GL11.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, sizeVBO[i]);
    GL11.glDisable(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D);

  } else //CRASHS HERE
    glDrawArrays(GL11.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, sizeVBO[i]);

}
```

resulting error:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00000000003ffe68, pid=4936, tid=4048
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_25-b18) (build 1.8.0_25-b18)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.25-b02 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  0x00000000003ffe68
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00000000003ef000):  JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=4048, stack(0x0000000002330000,0x0000000002430000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0x0000000000000000

Registers:
RAX=0x0000000058461574, RBX=0x0000000011fe0000, RCX=0x0000000000000000, RDX=0x0000000000000038
RSP=0x000000000242ee00, RBP=0x00000000bc7602a4, RSI=0x0000000000000000, RDI=0x0000000000000000
R8 =0x0000000000000000, R9 =0x0000000000000038, R10=0x0000000000000277, R11=0x0000000000410158
R12=0x0000000000000000, R13=0x00000000003ffdc0, R14=0x0000000000000009, R15=0x0000000000000038
RIP=0x00000000003ffe68, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010206

Top of Stack: (sp=0x000000000242ee00)
0x000000000242ee00:   ffffffffa6c87b00 0000000000000000
0x000000000242ee10:   0000000000000ce8 0000000011fe0000
0x000000000242ee20:   0000000000000038 000000005a9e84da
0x000000000242ee30:   0000000000000004 000000005a9cd07a
0x000000000242ee40:   0000000011fe0000 0000000000000000
0x000000000242ee50:   00000000003ef000 0000000000000004
0x000000000242ee60:   0000000057fe0080 0000000000000d20
0x000000000242ee70:   0000000000000000 000000005a9e6397
0x000000000242ee80:   0000000000000000 000000005484c780
0x000000000242ee90:   0000000011fe0000 0000000000000000
0x000000000242eea0:   000c000000003003 0080000000000000
0x000000000242eeb0:   000000000242efd8 000000005a6bfdc2
0x000000000242eec0:   0000000011fe0000 000000000242ef98
0x000000000242eed0:   0000000000000000 0000000000000004
0x000000000242eee0:   000000000242ef98 000000000242ef58
0x000000000242eef0:   000000000242ef58 000000000271a111 

Instructions: (pc=0x00000000003ffe68)
0x00000000003ffe48:   08 89 78 14 48 be 90 b3 02 12 00 00 00 00 48 8b
0x00000000003ffe58:   36 48 8b b6 c8 01 00 00 48 8d 3c 49 48 8d 34 be
0x00000000003ffe68:   8b 3e 8b 6e 04 89 78 18 89 68 1c 8b 7e 08 89 78
0x00000000003ffe78:   20 48 83 c0 24 ff c1 ff ca 0f 85 72 ff ff ff 48 


Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x0000000058461574 is an unknown value
RBX=0x0000000011fe0000 is an unknown value
RCX=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
RDX=0x0000000000000038 is an unknown value
RSP=0x000000000242ee00 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00000000003ef000
RBP=0x00000000bc7602a4 is an unknown value
RSI=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
RDI=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R8 =0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R9 =0x0000000000000038 is an unknown value
R10=0x0000000000000277 is an unknown value
R11=0x0000000000410158 is an unknown value
R12=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R13=0x00000000003ffdc0 is an unknown value
R14=0x0000000000000009 is an unknown value
R15=0x0000000000000038 is an unknown value


Stack: [0x0000000002330000,0x0000000002430000],  sp=0x000000000242ee00,  free space=1019k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  0x00000000003ffe68

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.nglDrawArrays(IIIJ)V+0
j  org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glDrawArrays(III)V+20
j  ogl.gui.obj.ObjectOGL.paint3D(F)V+150
j  ogl.gui.obj.ComplexObjectOGL.paint3D(F)V+77
j  ogl.game.connect.BattleMapEditorOGL.paint3D(F)V+110
j  ogl.gui.MainAppOGL.renderGL(I)V+16
j  ogl.gui.MainAppOGL.start()V+28
j  ogl.gui.MainAppOGL.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+9
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x0000000058fbf000 JavaThread "LWJGL Timer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1040, stack(0x0000000059920000,0x0000000059a20000)]
  0x0000000056c12000 JavaThread "Java2D Disposer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4804, stack(0x0000000059710000,0x0000000059810000)]
  0x0000000054d8f800 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=976, stack(0x0000000056e70000,0x0000000056f70000)]
  0x0000000054d89800 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4272, stack(0x0000000056190000,0x0000000056290000)]
  0x0000000054d4f800 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2432, stack(0x0000000056510000,0x0000000056610000)]
  0x0000000054d4b800 JavaThread "JDWP Command Reader" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=4116, stack(0x00000000567b0000,0x00000000568b0000)]
  0x0000000054d3c800 JavaThread "JDWP Event Helper Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4304, stack(0x00000000566a0000,0x00000000567a0000)]
  0x0000000054d38000 JavaThread "JDWP Transport Listener: dt_socket" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1252, stack(0x0000000056410000,0x0000000056510000)]
  0x0000000054d28800 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3676, stack(0x0000000055eb0000,0x0000000055fb0000)]
  0x0000000054d27800 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3516, stack(0x0000000055c90000,0x0000000055d90000)]
  0x0000000054cc7800 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4364, stack(0x0000000055870000,0x0000000055970000)]
  0x0000000054cc0800 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3596, stack(0x00000000559f0000,0x0000000055af0000)]
=>0x00000000003ef000 JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=4048, stack(0x0000000002330000,0x0000000002430000)]

Other Threads:
  0x0000000054cbb000 VMThread [stack: 0x0000000055770000,0x0000000055870000] [id=3268]
  0x00000000568c5000 WatcherThread [stack: 0x0000000056fc0000,0x00000000570c0000] [id=4464]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap:
 PSYoungGen      total 18944K, used 18941K [0x00000000eab00000, 0x00000000ec000000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 16384K, 100% used [0x00000000eab00000,0x00000000ebb00000,0x00000000ebb00000)
  from space 2560K, 99% used [0x00000000ebb00000,0x00000000ebd7f4a0,0x00000000ebd80000)
  to   space 2560K, 0% used [0x00000000ebd80000,0x00000000ebd80000,0x00000000ec000000)
 ParOldGen       total 44032K, used 756K [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000c2b00000, 0x00000000eab00000)
  object space 44032K, 1% used [0x00000000c0000000,0x00000000c00bd238,0x00000000c2b00000)
 Metaspace       used 9280K, capacity 9467K, committed 9728K, reserved 1058816K
  class space    used 955K, capacity 986K, committed 1024K, reserved 1048576K

Card table byte_map: [0x0000000011ac0000,0x0000000011cd0000] byte_map_base: 0x00000000114c0000

Marking Bits: (ParMarkBitMap*) 0x000000005df7d490
 Begin Bits: [0x0000000012190000, 0x0000000013190000)
 End Bits:   [0x0000000013190000, 0x0000000014190000)

Polling page: 0x0000000000120000

CodeCache: size=245760Kb used=3758Kb max_used=3766Kb free=242001Kb
 bounds [0x0000000002700000, 0x0000000002ac0000, 0x0000000011700000]
 total_blobs=1472 nmethods=950 adapters=445
 compilation: enabled

Compilation events (10 events):
Event: 3.587 Thread 0x0000000054d4f800  893       4       java.util.ArrayList$SubList$1::hasNext (20 bytes)
Event: 3.587 Thread 0x0000000054d4f800 nmethod 893 0x0000000002a96b10 code [0x0000000002a96c40, 0x0000000002a96cd8]
Event: 3.587 Thread 0x0000000054d4f800  842       4       javax.vecmath.Matrix3f::setIdentity (46 bytes)
Event: 3.588 Thread 0x0000000054d4f800 nmethod 842 0x0000000002a96910 code [0x0000000002a96a40, 0x0000000002a96ab8]
Event: 3.588 Thread 0x0000000054d4f800  849       4       com.bulletphysics.$Stack::pop$com$bulletphysics$linearmath$Transform (21 bytes)
Event: 3.588 Thread 0x0000000054d4f800 nmethod 849 0x0000000002a96650 code [0x0000000002a96780, 0x0000000002a96858]
Event: 3.588 Thread 0x0000000054d4f800  859       4       javax.vecmath.Tuple3f::sub (40 bytes)
Event: 3.589 Thread 0x0000000054d4f800 nmethod 859 0x0000000002a96390 code [0x0000000002a964c0, 0x0000000002a96578]
Event: 3.607 Thread 0x0000000054d89800  952       3       ogl.matrix.tile.TileMap::getTile (25 bytes)
Event: 3.608 Thread 0x0000000054d89800 nmethod 952 0x0000000002a94a10 code [0x0000000002a94c00, 0x0000000002a95628]

GC Heap History (2 events):
Event: 3.024 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=1 (full 0):
 PSYoungGen      total 18944K, used 16384K [0x00000000eab00000, 0x00000000ec000000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 16384K, 100% used [0x00000000eab00000,0x00000000ebb00000,0x00000000ebb00000)
  from space 2560K, 0% used [0x00000000ebd80000,0x00000000ebd80000,0x00000000ec000000)
  to   space 2560K, 0% used [0x00000000ebb00000,0x00000000ebb00000,0x00000000ebd80000)
 ParOldGen       total 44032K, used 0K [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000c2b00000, 0x00000000eab00000)
  object space 44032K, 0% used [0x00000000c0000000,0x00000000c0000000,0x00000000c2b00000)
 Metaspace       used 8681K, capacity 8751K, committed 8960K, reserved 1056768K
  class space    used 885K, capacity 918K, committed 1024K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 3.032 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=1 (full 0):
 PSYoungGen      total 18944K, used 2557K [0x00000000eab00000, 0x00000000ec000000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 16384K, 0% used [0x00000000eab00000,0x00000000eab00000,0x00000000ebb00000)
  from space 2560K, 99% used [0x00000000ebb00000,0x00000000ebd7f4a0,0x00000000ebd80000)
  to   space 2560K, 0% used [0x00000000ebd80000,0x00000000ebd80000,0x00000000ec000000)
 ParOldGen       total 44032K, used 756K [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000c2b00000, 0x00000000eab00000)
  object space 44032K, 1% used [0x00000000c0000000,0x00000000c00bd238,0x00000000c2b00000)
 Metaspace       used 8681K, capacity 8751K, committed 8960K, reserved 1056768K
  class space    used 885K, capacity 918K, committed 1024K, reserved 1048576K
}

Deoptimization events (0 events):
No events

Internal exceptions (10 events):
Event: 3.480 Thread 0x00000000003ef000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000ebaa43a0) thrown at [D:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u25\1677\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1312]
Event: 3.484 Thread 0x00000000003ef000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000ebaa5a38) thrown at [D:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u25\1677\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1312]
Event: 3.490 Thread 0x00000000003ef000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000ebaa70c0) thrown at [D:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u25\1677\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1312]
Event: 3.523 Thread 0x00000000003ef000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000ebaa87c0) thrown at [D:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u25\1677\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1312]
Event: 3.526 Thread 0x00000000003ef000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000ebaa9ef0) thrown at [D:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u25\1677\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1312]
Event: 3.529 Thread 0x00000000003ef000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000ebaab5d8) thrown at [D:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u25\1677\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1312]
Event: 3.568 Thread 0x00000000003ef000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000ebaaccb8) thrown at [D:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u25\1677\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1312]
Event: 3.590 Thread 0x00000000003ef000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000ebaae398) thrown at [D:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u25\1677\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1312]
Event: 3.600 Thread 0x00000000003ef000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000ebaafa68) thrown at [D:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u25\1677\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1312]
Event: 3.603 Thread 0x00000000003ef000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000ebab10b8) thrown at [D:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u25\1677\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1312]

Events (10 events):
Event: 23.658 Executing VM operation: GetOrSetLocal
Event: 23.658 Executing VM operation: GetOrSetLocal done
Event: 29.716 Executing VM operation: EnterInterpOnlyMode
Event: 29.716 Executing VM operation: EnterInterpOnlyMode done
Event: 29.716 Executing VM operation: GetCurrentLocation
Event: 29.716 Executing VM operation: GetCurrentLocation done
Event: 29.716 Executing VM operation: ChangeSingleStep
Event: 29.717 Executing VM operation: ChangeSingleStep done
Event: 29.718 Executing VM operation: ChangeSingleStep
Event: 29.718 Executing VM operation: ChangeSingleStep done


Dynamic libraries:
0x000000013fb10000 - 0x000000013fb44000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_25\bin\javaw.exe
0x0000000076db0000 - 0x0000000076f5a000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
0x0000000076c90000 - 0x0000000076db0000     C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll
0x000007fefcc00000 - 0x000007fefcc6b000     C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
0x000007fefedd0000 - 0x000007fefeeab000     C:\Windows\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x000007fefebd0000 - 0x000007fefec6f000     C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
0x000007fefd910000 - 0x000007fefd92f000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\sechost.dll
0x000007fefd330000 - 0x000007fefd45d000     C:\Windows\system32\RPCRT4.dll
0x0000000076b90000 - 0x0000000076c8a000     C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll
0x000007fefd4c0000 - 0x000007fefd527000     C:\Windows\system32\GDI32.dll
0x000007fefe740000 - 0x000007fefe74e000     C:\Windows\system32\LPK.dll
0x000007fefd530000 - 0x000007fefd5fa000     C:\Windows\system32\USP10.dll
0x000007fefb320000 - 0x000007fefb514000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.7601.17514_none_fa396087175ac9ac\COMCTL32.dll
0x000007fefd600000 - 0x000007fefd671000     C:\Windows\system32\SHLWAPI.dll
0x000007fefd680000 - 0x000007fefd6ae000     C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.DLL
0x000007fefeac0000 - 0x000007fefebc9000     C:\Windows\system32\MSCTF.dll
0x0000000065ba0000 - 0x0000000065c72000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_25\bin\msvcr100.dll
0x000000005d7a0000 - 0x000000005dffa000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_25\bin\server\jvm.dll
0x000007feef2c0000 - 0x000007feef2c9000     C:\Windows\system32\WSOCK32.dll
0x000007fefcf30000 - 0x000007fefcf7d000     C:\Windows\system32\WS2_32.dll
0x000007fefd6b0000 - 0x000007fefd6b8000     C:\Windows\system32\NSI.dll
0x000007fef94a0000 - 0x000007fef94db000     C:\Windows\system32\WINMM.dll
0x0000000076f80000 - 0x0000000076f87000     C:\Windows\system32\PSAPI.DLL
0x0000000073af0000 - 0x0000000073aff000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_25\bin\verify.dll
0x0000000073070000 - 0x0000000073098000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_25\bin\java.dll
0x0000000071030000 - 0x0000000071065000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_25\bin\jdwp.dll
0x0000000073060000 - 0x0000000073068000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_25\bin\npt.dll
0x00000000730b0000 - 0x00000000730c6000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_25\bin\zip.dll
0x000007fefd9b0000 - 0x000007fefe739000     C:\Windows\system32\SHELL32.dll
0x000007fefeeb0000 - 0x000007feff0b3000     C:\Windows\system32\ole32.dll
0x000007fefcb70000 - 0x000007fefcb7f000     C:\Windows\system32\profapi.dll
0x0000000072fb0000 - 0x0000000072fb9000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_25\bin\dt_socket.dll
0x000007fefaa80000 - 0x000007fefaa95000     C:\Windows\system32\NLAapi.dll
0x000007fefa330000 - 0x000007fefa345000     C:\Windows\system32\napinsp.dll
0x000007fefa120000 - 0x000007fefa139000     C:\Windows\system32\pnrpnsp.dll
0x000007fefc370000 - 0x000007fefc3c5000     C:\Windows\System32\mswsock.dll
0x000007fefc1f0000 - 0x000007fefc24b000     C:\Windows\system32\DNSAPI.dll
0x000007fefa630000 - 0x000007fefa63b000     C:\Windows\System32\winrnr.dll
0x000007fefa670000 - 0x000007fefa697000     C:\Windows\system32\IPHLPAPI.DLL
0x000007fefa660000 - 0x000007fefa66b000     C:\Windows\system32\WINNSI.DLL
0x000007fef9fa0000 - 0x000007fef9ff3000     C:\Windows\System32\fwpuclnt.dll
0x000007fefa320000 - 0x000007fefa328000     C:\Windows\system32\rasadhlp.dll
0x000007fefbd10000 - 0x000007fefbd17000     C:\Windows\System32\wshtcpip.dll
0x0000000180000000 - 0x0000000180064000     C:\Users\Demon\workspace\ogl\native\windows\OpenAL64.dll
0x0000000011e30000 - 0x0000000011e83000     C:\Users\Demon\workspace\ogl\native\windows\lwjgl64.dll
0x000007feedbd0000 - 0x000007feedced000     C:\Windows\system32\OPENGL32.dll
0x000007fef9a20000 - 0x000007fef9a4d000     C:\Windows\system32\GLU32.dll
0x000007feeb770000 - 0x000007feeb861000     C:\Windows\system32\DDRAW.dll
0x000007fef9aa0000 - 0x000007fef9aa8000     C:\Windows\system32\DCIMAN32.dll
0x000007fefe8e0000 - 0x000007fefeab7000     C:\Windows\system32\SETUPAPI.dll
0x000007fefcd20000 - 0x000007fefcd56000     C:\Windows\system32\CFGMGR32.dll
0x000007fefcf80000 - 0x000007fefd057000     C:\Windows\system32\OLEAUT32.dll
0x000007fefcf10000 - 0x000007fefcf2a000     C:\Windows\system32\DEVOBJ.dll
0x000007fefa8a0000 - 0x000007fefa8b8000     C:\Windows\system32\dwmapi.dll
0x000007fefbc40000 - 0x000007fefbc4c000     C:\Windows\system32\VERSION.dll
0x000007fefb140000 - 0x000007fefb196000     C:\Windows\system32\uxtheme.dll
0x000007feed2a0000 - 0x000007feed2e8000     C:\Users\Demon\AppData\Local\Temp\TeamViewer\tv_x64.dll
0x0000000059e90000 - 0x000000005bac0000     C:\Windows\system32\nvoglv64.DLL
0x000007fefcba0000 - 0x000007fefcbdb000     C:\Windows\system32\WINTRUST.dll
0x000007fefcd60000 - 0x000007fefcecd000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPT32.dll
0x000007fefcb80000 - 0x000007fefcb8f000     C:\Windows\system32\MSASN1.dll
0x000007fefaef0000 - 0x000007fefaf1d000     C:\Windows\system32\ntmarta.dll
0x000007fefd460000 - 0x000007fefd4b2000     C:\Windows\system32\WLDAP32.dll
0x000007fefca10000 - 0x000007fefca1f000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTBASE.dll
0x000007fef94e0000 - 0x000007fef957c000     C:\Windows\system32\mscms.dll
0x000007fefced0000 - 0x000007fefceef000     C:\Windows\system32\USERENV.dll
0x000007fef1a60000 - 0x000007fef1aa2000     C:\Windows\system32\icm32.dll
0x0000000059cf0000 - 0x0000000059e88000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_25\bin\awt.dll
0x000007fef0e10000 - 0x000007fef0f35000     C:\Windows\system32\dbghelp.dll

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,suspend=y,address=localhost:50127 -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252 
java_command: ogl.gui.MainAppOGL
java_class_path (initial): C:\Users\Demon\workspace\ogl\bin;C:\Users\Demon\workspace\ogl\lib\lwjgl_util.jar;C:\Users\Demon\workspace\ogl\lib\lwjgl.jar;C:\Users\Demon\workspace\game\bin;C:\Users\Demon\workspace\jbox2d-library\target\classes;C:\Users\Demon\workspace\jbox2d-library\target\test-classes;C:\Users\Demon\Downloads\eclipse-jee-luna-SR2-win32-x86_64\eclipse\plugins\org.junit_4.11.0.v201303080030\junit.jar;C:\Users\Demon\workspace\math\bin;C:\Users\Demon\workspace\game\lib\asm-all-3.1.jar;C:\Users\Demon\workspace\game\lib\jbullet.jar;C:\Users\Demon\workspace\game\lib\stack-alloc.jar;C:\Users\Demon\workspace\game\lib\swing-layout-1.0.3.jar;C:\Users\Demon\workspace\game\lib\vecmath.jar;C:\Users\Demon\workspace\ui\bin
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
PATH=C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_25/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_25/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_25/lib/amd64;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Users\Demon\Downloads\eclipse-jee-luna-SR2-win32-x86_64\eclipse;
USERNAME=Demon
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 23 Stepping 6, GenuineIntel



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows 7 , 64 bit Build 7601 Service Pack 1

CPU:total 2 (2 cores per cpu, 1 threads per core) family 6 model 23 stepping 6, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, tsc

Memory: 4k page, physical 4193396k(1615584k free), swap 8384932k(5290520k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.25-b02) for windows-amd64 JRE (1.8.0_25-b18), built on Oct  7 2014 14:25:37 by "java_re" with MS VC++ 10.0 (VS2010)

time: Fri May 22 23:50:01 2015
elapsed time: 29 seconds (0d 0h 0m 29s)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it:

```
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

...

glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glDisableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
```

All client states have to be deactivated after every call on NVIDIA components.

Comment: I have been struggling with this exact issue for a couple years now; I am SOO glad you found the answer!
I would be interested to know where you found out about specifically enabling/disabling for each glDrawArrays call for NVIDIA gpus.